# What permissions does my android app request?

Tags: android, permissions, apk

I know(am I wrong?) that an Android app may request more permissions than specified in manifest file. 
E.g. compiling with google play services, or some other third party libraries include permissions I am not aware of.
Is there a way to list all required permissions after building APK file?
I want to know of all requested permissions before publishing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an Android app may request more permissions than specified in manifest file

- on the manifest that the developer wrote him/herself yes, but on the manifest actually inside the .apk all the permissions are there
- on android studio you can go to the manifest file and on the bottom left there's a little tab that says "merged manifest" that shows what your manifest will be on the final .apk.

[image: see image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! So close to, and so hard to notice :)